# Supervisor does not restart on econnrefused (thrown in init/1)

Tags: erlang, erlang-otp, erlang-supervisor

I have a gen_server's `init` function I connect to rabbitmq. When all is good then it works perfectly fine however when connecting to rabbitmq fails and I call `exit` the process is not restarted.

I would like to make supervisor restart this process after me calling `exit`.

Conceptually my `init` function is like this:

```
init(_Args) ->
  process_flag(trap_exit, true),
  case connect() of
    {error, econnrefused} ->
            timer:sleep(1000),
            exit(econnrefused);
    {ok, Connection} ->
            .....
  end,
  {ok, {}}.
```

And here is my supervisor:

```
-module(tasks_manager_sup).
-behaviour(supervisor).
-export([start_link/0]).
-export([init/1]).
-define(SERVER, ?MODULE).

start_link() ->
    supervisor:start_link({local, ?SERVER}, ?MODULE, []).

init([]) ->
    {ok,
     {#{strategy => one_for_one, 
        intensity => 50,
        period => 10},
      [#{id => tasks_manager_serv_id,
         start => {tasks_manager_serv, start_link, []},
         restart => permanent,
         shutdown => brutal_kill,
         type => worker,
         modules => [tasks_manager_serv]}]}}.
```

The error I recive is as follows. You can see that there are no restarts on this error, it just terminates:

```
Starting {global,tasks_da_serv} (<0.479.0>)
Starting {global,tasks_manager_serv} (<0.483.0>)

 =INFO REPORT==== 9-Jun-2017::09:52:46 ===
     application: tasks
     exited: {{shutdown,
                  {failed_to_start_child,tasks_manager_sup_id,
                      {shutdown,
                          {failed_to_start_child,tasks_manager_serv_id,
                              econnrefused}}}},
              {tasks_app,start,[normal,[]]}}
     type: permanent
 {"Kernel pid terminated",application_controller,"{application_start_failure,tasks,{{shutdown,{failed_to_start_child,tasks_manager_sup_id,{shutdown,{failed_to_start_child,tasks_manager_serv_id,econnrefused}}}},{tasks_app,start,[normal,[]]}}}"}
 Kernel pid terminated (application_controller) ({application_start_failure,tasks,{{shutdown,{failed_to_start_child,tasks_manager_sup_id,{shutdown,{failed_to_start_child,tasks_manager_serv_id,econnrefu
```

I've tried also casting a message to `self()` (from `init` function) and connecting to rabbit in `handle_cast` but it does not work as well.

I'm still learning Erlang/OTP so forgive me if I'm asking about something obvious but I couldn't find any answer in the docs to my problem.

Comment: I can't find this documented, but it looks like the Supervisor is not restarting the process because it exits in `init`. It does restart it for me if I add `self() ! connect` and then exit in `handle_info(connect, ...)`.

Comment: @Dogbert, The [supervisor:start_link() docs](http://erldocs.com/current/stdlib/supervisor.html?i=5&search=supervisor:star#start_link/3)? ---> _If the supervisor and its child processes are successfully created (that is, if all child process start functions return {ok,Child}, {ok,Child,Info}, or ignore), the function returns {ok,Pid}, where Pid is the pid of the supervisor....If Module:init/1 fails or returns an incorrect value, this function returns {error,Term}, where Term is a term with information about the error, and **the supervisor terminates with reason Term**_

Comment: In other words, you have to be able to get the supervisor's children started the first time--otherwise the supervisor process will not be created.

Comment: @7stud It's not the `supervisor` that is not starting in the OP question, but a `gen_server` that is started by it.

Comment: The supervisor child start does have to succeed, but there's nothing to stop you engineering `init/1` to try to connect multiple times before finally giving up. If the supervisor starts other children that expect the rabbitmq facility to be available then this is probably better than allowing it to start and asynchronously trying to connect... Do you actually need to retry though? If you connect without retrying, the whole app then fails relatively quickly due to the external resource not being available and it's clear to administrators who can then deal with it.

Comment: @Michael Sometimes unexpected thing can happen and connection will fail (IDK cable monkey?). So restarting it few times could be a good idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to comments below the question I was able to solve it.
Basically the problem was that the process was not started correctly because `exit(econnrefused)` was in `init/1` function. That's why supervisor was not restarting the process - it does not restarts processes which are failing to initialize.

Now I'm sending a message to `self()` and then catch it in `hangle_info/2` like this:

```
init(_Args) ->
    process_flag(trap_exit, true),
    io:format("Starting ~p (~p)~n", [{global, ?MODULE}, self()]),
    self() ! connect,
    {ok, {}}.

handle_info(connect, State) ->
    {ok, Connection, Channel} = establish_rabbit_connection(),
    {noreply, #state{connection = Connection, channel = Channel}};
```